# Find the number of elements in $s$ as per following criteria

Tags: combinatorics, solution-verification, problem-solving

Let $$s=\left\{\left(x_{1}, x_{2}, x_{3}\right) \mid 0 \leq x_{i} \leq 9 \text { and } x_{1}+x_{2}+x_{3} \text { is divisible by } 3\right\}$$
Then the number of elements in s is

---

**My approach**

With each $\left(x_{1}, x_{2}, x_{3}\right)$ identify a three digit code, where reading zeros are allowed.  There is  a bijection between s and the set of all non-negative integers less than or equal to 999 divisible by $3 .$ The no. of numbers between 1 and 999 , inclusive, divisible by 3 is $\left(\frac{999}{3}\right)=333$
Also,  $0$ is divisible by 3 . Hence, the number of elements in $s$ is $=333+1=334$

*Am I correct?*
**please tell me if u have any better approach(if possible tell me any general approach,which will fit for all type of this problem)**

Comment: your approach is perfect.

Comment: You should mention you are relying upon the sum of digit results. Also you'd need another method if the question was, say, $x_1+x_2+x_3$ is divisible by $4$ say.

Comment: yeah that's why I am looking for another approach

Comment: I must say your approach is easier and *is* correct.

Comment: Like u have said , what can I do If divisible by 4?

Comment: One way could be to decide which forms are allowed for $x_i$  from $3k,3k+1,3k+2$ so that their sum is divisible by $3$.

Comment: one way I have thought applying partition method. It will be applicable for any of the case. But it is tedious

Answer (score 1):

I'd be more inclined to be more direct.

$x_i \equiv 0,1 ,2$.  There are $4$ cases where $x_i \equiv 0\equiv 0\equiv 3\equiv 6 \equiv 9\pmod 3$.  And there are $3$ case where $x_i \equiv k\not\equiv 0 \pmod 3$.  They are, if $k\equiv 1,2\pmod 3$, $x_i\equiv k\equiv k+3\equiv k+6\pmod 3$

If $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 \equiv 0 \pmod 3$ then $x_3 \equiv -(x_1 + x_2)\pmod 3$.

If $-(x_1 + x_2) \equiv 0\pmod 3$ there are $4$ ways $x_3\equiv -(x_1 + x_2)$.  But if $-(x_1+x_2) \not \equiv 0 \pmod 3$ there are $3$ ways $x_3 \equiv -(x_1 + x_2)$.

So the total number of ways are

$4\cdot\text{number of ways }[-(x_1+x_2)\equiv 0]+3\cdot\text{number of ways }[-(x_1+x_2)\not \equiv 0]$

$-(x_1 + x_2) \equiv 0 \iff x_2\equiv -x_1$.  If $x_1 \equiv 0$ (there are four ways that could occur) then $x_2\equiv 0$ (ditto) and there are $4\cdot 4-16$ ways that could occur.  If $x_1 \not \equiv 0$ there are $6$ ways that could occur.  Then if $x_2 \equiv -x_1\not \equiv 0$ there are $3$ ways that could occur.  So there are $6\cdot 3=18$ that $-(x_1+x_2) \equiv 0; x_1\not \equiv 0$ can occur.

So $\text{number of ways }[-(x_1+x_2)\equiv 0]=16 + 18=34$.

If $-(x_1 + x_2)\not \equiv 0\iff x_2 \not \equiv -x_1$.  If $x_1\equiv 0$ (there are four ways) then $x_2 \not \equiv 0$ (there are six ways).  If $x_1\not \equiv 0$ (there are six ways).  Then there are $3$ ways $x_2 \equiv -x_1$ and $10-3 =7$ ways $x_2 \not \equiv -x_1$.

So $\text{number of ways }[-(x_1+x_2)\not \equiv 0]=4\cdot 6 + 6\cdot 7=24 + 42=66$

so the number of ways that $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 \equiv 0$ are

$4\cdot 34 + 3\cdot 66 = 136 + 198 = 334$.

......

But all said and done, I think your way is easier and more clever.

Note $x_1 + x_2 + x_3\equiv 0 \pmod 3 \iff 100x_1 + 10x_2 + x_3 \equiv 0\pmod 3$.

And as you point out $f: \{(x_1, x_2, x_3)\} \to \{0,...,999\}$ via $f((x_1, x_2, x_3)) = 100x_1 + 10x_2 + x_3$ is a bijection.

Then number of elements where $x_1 + x_2+x_3$ are divisible by $3$ is the number numbers between $0$ and $999$ divisible by $3$ so .... $334$.

Much easier.

But relies on the sum of three in base ten rule....

Can we generalize it to how many or divisible by $k$ where $k$ *isn't* $3$ or $9$?

Let me get back to you on that.

Comment: Thanks! exactly looking for that solution which supports divisible by k where k isn't 3 or 9

Answer (score 0):

Your method is the best. However an alternative (and a bit tedious ) approach is as follows 
We have numbers each of the forms $3k:\{0,3,6,9\}$, $3k+1:\{1,4,7\}$ and $3k+2:\{2,5,8\}$. For $x_1+x_2+x_3$ to be divisible by $3$ :- 
1.each of them must be of the same form$ \left[2\left(3! {3\choose3}+{3\choose1}{2\choose1}\frac{3!}{2!}+{3\choose1}\right)+\left(3! {4\choose3}+{4\choose1}{3\choose1}\frac{3!}{2!}+{4\choose1}\right)\right]=118$, or  
 2.each of them must be of different forms. 
$\left[{4\choose1}{3\choose1}{3\choose1}3!\right]=216$  
 Thus counting the total no. of permutations we get $118+216=334$.

Comment: The first case: $4^3+3^3+3^3=118$